# Socket.receive return 0 second time but there is data in the port

Tags: sockets

I am programming a server application to receive requests and answer using the vb.net socket class.  I am using the socket.receive and first time is ok but the second time it always return 0 bytes.   I can see, with a sniffer, that there is data in the port. I can see that we past the 3 first steps of the communication good and I can see the data in the port, but my socket.receive instruction always return 0 bytes (Sometimes it works the first time and the second stop but some times since the first time it return 0)
I have followed a lot of recommendation found but nothing works, for example: Use the socket.available before the instruction socket.receive, put the socket.receive in a cycle to wait for the complete message, clear the socket buffer.
This is the portion of my code for the socket.receive instruction:

```
Try
    While True
      If vConnectionSocket.Available > 0 Then
        vNumOfBytesReceived = vConnectionSocket.Receive(Data, 0, vMessageLength, SocketFlags.None)
        Array.Copy(Data, indbuf, vClientMessage, indbuf, vNumOfBytesReceived)

        If vStrMsg.IndexOf(ChrW(3)) > -1 Then
          Exit While
        End If
        Array.Clear(Data, 0, Data.Length)
      End If
    End While
Catch ex As SocketException
  If vConnectionSocket.Connected Then vConnectionSocket.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Receiving error >" + ex.ErrorCode.ToString + ":" + ex.Message.ToString)   
  Exit Sub
End Try
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329735.aspx):

> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter. **If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes**.

In other words, when Receive() return 0, the connection was closed by the other party.  There is no more data available to read.  Close your end of the connection.

Comment: Thanks Remy for your answer But I`m sure that the connection was not closed because I can see with the sniffer that data is comming to the port.

Comment: The only way `Receive()` can return 0 when `Available` returns >0 is if either `vMessageLength` is 0 or the connection has been closed.

Comment: Remy, in fact available is returning 0 but help me: How is posible that Avaiable is returning 0 when there is data in the port?

Comment: Your code is calling `Receive()` only when `Available > 0`. If `Available` is returning 0, then there is no pending data waiting for the socket to read it, including data for a graceful disconnect. If you see data on the port but the socket is not reacting to it, then the socket has likely been closed abnormally. The OS cannot usually detect abnormal disconnects in a timely manner, it has to wait for the socket to time out internally first.

Comment: Very interesting Remy. What about this: I have this situation with a client, but I have my own client application (for testing ) that send data to the same IP/Port, and my Server application receive this data and send response perfectly, but for the real client the situation persist. WHy the server application has this different behavior for different clients?

Comment: You will have to use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to watch the socket communication and see what is different between the two connections. This is likely to be a clien-side issue, not a server-side issue. Most likely, the failing client simply hasa bug in it that is preventing its socket from working correctly. There hasn't been enough information or code presented here to diagnose that kind of issue.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your recomendations. My application had two problemas: 1. A time out very short that close the socket, then the communication can´t finish. 2. Allways spects a NEW connection from the client and accept only ONE communication from each client. I add a loop to the thread that read messages from the client while the available is > 0.   My application is working now! Thanks again!